# Concerning the word, "schwarzbraun;" Does this term, when applied to a person, literally mean "blackbrown", or connote "brunette"?

Tags: meaning, idiom

[1] Concerning the word, **"schwarzbraun**;" Does this term, when applied to a person, literally mean "black brown", or connote "brunette"?

[2] Does schwarzbraun suggest a mood-as "blue" connotes sadness or depression  in the English language?

This adjective is used in several older Lieder-specifically, "Schwarzbraun ist die Hazelnuss" and a military march, "Wenn wir marschieren" as "Schwarzbraunes Mädel, du bleibst zuhaus."

Comment: This may not be very helpful, but I mainly associate "schwarzbraun" with IKEA, which uses that word as a color description for some of its furniture. For example https://www.ikea.com/at/de/p/kallax-regal-schwarzbraun-10275862/

Answer (score 8):

First of all, *Schwarzbraun* is simply a color with which no mood is associated: a very dark brown that can only be distinguished from black on closer inspection<sup>1</sup>.

In relation to a person - as for example in the song *Schwarzbraun ist die Haselnuss* - it obviously refers to the color of the hair. I imagine brunette to be a distinct brown, but that's probably a matter of opinion.

The motif of the *black-brown girl* has appeared in numerous folk songs since the 16th century and, according to Lutz Röhrich<sup>2</sup>, describes a "gripping, hearty type" in contrast to the image of a "brittle, blonde woman".
In my opinion, the designation of people with an external characteristic such as hair color is rightly rejected today. Needless to say, a connection between hair color and other characteristic traits is obviously nonsense.

As the song *Schwarzbraun ist die Haselnuss* in particular was probably very popular with soldiers and was often used as marching music in the First and Second World Wars, it is rather frowned upon today. Its use as marching music was declared expressly undesirable by the Federal Ministry of Defense and it was removed from the Bundeswehr's official songbook<sup>3</sup>.

To what extent *black-brown* is supposed to be connected with *national socialist exaggeration* is not clear to me. After all, the Nazi ideal was rather the opposite.

---

1: https://www.ralfarbpalette.de/ral-classic/ral-8022-schwarzbraun

2: Lutz Röhrich: Liebesmetaphorik im Volkslied. In: D. K. Wilgus (Ed.), Folklore international, essays in traditional literature, belief, and custom in honor of Wayland Debs Hand. Hatboro, PA.1967. S. 187 ff.

3: https://www.suedkurier.de/ueberregional/politik/Diese-Lieder-sind-bei-der-Bundeswehr-kuenftig-unerwuenscht;art410924,9253537

Comment: A Nazi connotation to "schwarzbraun" is, I think, a bit far-fetched - They were rather seen in yellow-brown tones. (My grandma used to denote them as "Gelbhemden". The songs, however, were heavily contaminated during Nazi times.

Comment: For me, the "schwarzbraun" in "schwarzbraun ist die Haselnuss" was always a coded hint at political opinion - after all, the nazis called themselves the brown party, and "schwarzbraun" could be seen as "deep, uncompromising brown". Of course, the song dates from the end of the 18th century - so predates nazis by a long time - but phrases that **might** hint at nazism are considered heavily tainted in Germany. Just compare to "To each their own", "Jedem das Seine", which dates back to the roman empire, but will get you in big trouble if you use it in Germany.

Comment: Politically, "schwarz" refers to the conservative parties CDU and CSU (like opposed to "rot" which classically refers to the left wing (basically everywhere but not in the USA). Sometimes (or rather quite frequently) politicians of this party try to court voters with extreme right-wing opinions. The brown ones. So "schwarzbraun" means the "gray area" or the fuzzy border between black (middle-right) and brown (extreme right). It also refers to the fact that after the war previous Nazis would vote for or make a career in CDU/CSU.

Comment: So "schwarzbraun" may refer to a person who pretends to be just conservative ("scharz") but who has actually extreme right-wing opinions (brown). But all this what I said makes sense only post WWII.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it focused more on the meanings of the words and less on ideological rants. "designation of people with an external characteristic such as hair color is rightly rejected today" - it's not necessarily a "designation", it's a description. Or does the world change so rapidly that I failed to notice that even mentioning or describing or even noticing someone's hair color is a crime? Someone having hair (or skin, or eyes) of a certain color is just a fact.

Comment: @vsz Read the paragraph about *schwarzbraun* in folk songs according to Lutz Röhrich again! The questions about the meaning are answered. Additional information ia about the song mentioned in the question.

Comment: As a German, I have never heard the term "schwarzbraun" in a political or nazi context. Braun? Yes. Schwarz? Yes. But Schwarzbraun as a political association is just not a thing.

Comment: As a German, I can understand how all the sentiments in this answer can arise in our current day and age, but I have not, ever, in decades, had any of the connotations mentioned or alluded here, neither racial nor national socialist. I know the term from Heino's version of the song, which post-dates WW2, and nothing could be farther from my mind than any Nazi or otherwise military connotations to it. I checked the song text on Wikipedia, and there is simply nothing disreputable there, whatsoever, no hidden meanings, nothing at all. Just a heads-up to OP.

Comment: @AnoE I have no idea what sentiments you are talking about. I never said that the cited connection between blackbrown hair and "gripping, hearty" / blond hair "brittle" would be racist. I said it's nonsense. Don't project. Neither is any military connection my idea. Just check the sources.

Comment: @Olafant "I have no idea what sentiments you are talking about" - OP is asking mostly about whether the term means more "black" or "brunette"; and whether it describes a mood like "blue = sad". Your answer is very fine up to the second part starting with "In my opinion, the designation of people..." - from there on it's all about associations, nazi, armies etc.. Yes, you do word it such that you say all of that is *not* applicable, but why notice it in the first place? OP gives no hint that he is much interested about these topics in his question, nor even that he knows about them...

Comment: @AnoE Just because you never heard about it and don't want to hear it doesn't mean it's irrelevant.

Comment: Oh for sure, @Olafant. I'm not trying to shut you down, I'm just in the habit of giving a comment whenever downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

The *[Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schwarzbraun)* defines *schwarzbraun* as a hue of color that contains both black and brown components ("Farbton, der sowohl schwarze als auch braune Anteile enthält"). The *[Duden Wörterbuch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwarzbraun)* defines *schwarzbraun* as a deep dark brown that almost transitions into black ("tief dunkelbraun und fast in Schwarz übergehend").

The DWDS corpus [shows](https://www.dwds.de/wp/?q=schwarzbraun&comp-method=diff&comp=&display=lemma&pos=Adjektiv&minstat=0&minfreq=5&by=logDice&limit=100&view=table&table=&mode=) that *schwarzbraun* is mostly used in descriptions of animals and less frequently in descriptions of human hair and skin, specifically of women. It has no mood connotation, i.e. there is no "blackbrown mood".

As [the Wikipedia article explains](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzbraun_ist_die_Haselnuss), in the folk song "Schwarzbraun ist die Haselnuss" the color refers to a woman's hair. Folklorist Barbara Boock assumes that the hair color is intended to describe a "hands-on, hearty type" of woman, in contrast to the "brittle, light type of woman who often occupies a higher social rank".

The song has no racist implications. The only connection to German nationalism is that [it was a popular marching song among soldiers in the second world war](https://www.lieder-archiv.de/schwarzbraun_ist_die_haselnuss-notenblatt_300393.html). Note that the song's narrator mentions that he is blackbrown, too ("schwarzbraun bin auch ich").

Comment: What information does your answer add that wasn't already given in my answer?

Comment: @Olafant (1) It cites two standard dictionaries instead of only giving my own ideas about the meaning of the word. (2) It gives a source that shows that the word is also used to describe skin color, not only hair. (3) It links to a folklorist opinion that is available freely online and not only in a printed book. (4) It explains why the song appears problematic today and why it cannot be considered racist or nationalist in and of itself, and avoids assumptions and your statement that "you don't know". (5) My answer is well-structured. (6) It points out the reference to the singer of the song.

Comment: (1) I'm sure OP can look up words in a dictionary. I'm linking to the RAL-standard palette. (2) Nobody was asking about animals. (3) The opinion of a folklorist about one song instead of an essay about the use of the term in folk songs since the 16th century? Ok. (4)(a) as my answer does (4)(b) you just state your opinion in opposition to other opinions in a widespread discussion for many years and btw. in the comments to my answer (5) So is mine. (6) There is nothing like **the** singer of a folk song. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z071fl5p0Rw

Comment: @olafant There is no particular requirement on SE that an answer must contain specific "new information". This answer is wildly different from the original answer in tone and direction, and much more suited IMO. The voting mechanism takes care of this.

Comment: @Olafant "There is nothing like the singer of a folk song." — Yes, that part of my comment was imprecisely phrased. I don't know if you are familiar with narratological terms and tried to avoid them. What I meant was the *[narrator](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erz%C3%A4hlperspektive)*.